# rails test error:"table projectname_test.destroys doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rails-activerecord, destroy

I just started to learn Ruby on Rails. And when I used the rails to do the test, an error occurred as: 
UserTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'eula_test.destroys' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `destroys`
I don't know what is eula_test.destroys and how should I solve this problem.

Comment: Have you created this table ?

Comment: Should I create this table manually? What is the function of this table, and what are the columns?

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

check your migration files. on db/migrate.rb and db/shema.rb you can check out if you have that table.

Comment: I don't have that table, but i don't remember I have used that table also.What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Seems no-one has been able to answer this, but best guess based on the error you are getting it looks like you need a join table because you most likely have a "has_and_belongs_to_many" directive in both your models eula.rb and test.rb

So you need to create a migration: rails g migration CreateEulaTest

then edit the migration to include an index that tells the db to look in eula_test table for the data to join with.

you need edit your migration with the following:

```
 def up 
  create_table :eula_test, :id => false do |t|
   t.integer :eula_id 
   t.integer :test_id 
 end
 add_index(:eula_test, [:eula_id, :test_id]
end
 def down
  drop_table :eula_test
 end
end
```

Note: this table does not require it's own ID hence the :id => false 
Also, the add_index portion are your foreign keys between the 2 models that allows the database to know that you are going through the table to establish your directive, such as create and destroy etc.

run rails db:migrate for rails 5 or greater, rake db:migrate <5

You may need to check your models to ensure you have the correct has_to_and_belongs_to_many settings.

It is likely you missed this part of the tutorial. Some tutorials don't explain why things are done, they just show you the code and let you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`rails db:reset` should fix it :)

Comment: Why? Adding more explanation makes your answer more useful.

Comment: Rails has some mechanism to updating test database in background. I cannot say the exact details, but saw that, by example with `rails db:migrate` my test-database-structure was updated, or, to say, synced with the development database. The same by `db:reset`.

Comment: I don't know Rails, sorry. Just wanted to say you can make your answer better by providing more explanation. :)